# spark streaming write data to spark-sql, but cann't query it

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have submitted a streaming application, and write DataFram to spark-sql.

```
df.show(5)
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable(s"industy.test1")
```

when i send some message to kafka, the line df.show(5) have printed in the log file, that means i have successfully consumed the data, but when i use the zeppelin and the spark-sql interactive command line to query industry.test1, there is no data that i have consumed. And the log file has not any errors, but when i reopened a spark-sql interactive command line to query table, i got the data. So i want to know why i need to reopen it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you tried with just .saveAsTable("industy.test1")

Comment: @Vijay Krishna yes